# how to get selected item of combo box

Tags: java-me, combobox, lwuit

i'm using lwuit with j2me . how to get combo box selected item or index? i found the function for [setSelectedIndex](http://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/ComboBox.html#setSelectedIndex%28int%29) but not for getting the selected.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use this code :

```
comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
```

To return the current selected offset in the list.

```
comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
```

To return the current selected item in the list or null for no selection

Comment: thanks bharath. may i  know the citation please. because i'm very much struggle to find the documentation

Comment: @Paniyar: look at here, [LWUIT Java documentation.](http://lwuit.java.net/nonav/javadocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

To get what you selected as a string:

```
String selected_text = ComboBox.getItemAt(ComboBox.getSelectedIndex());
```